# Taking Xml from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, entity-framework

I am developing one web application using Entity framework. Before this, i had used the Dataset for data manipulation. and now i changed to entity framework 4.0. My query is that, in the Dataset version we can take the xml values by using `Dataset.GetXml();` method. But i don't know how to take the same from Entity framework. If you have any idea about this, please share with me. If we can't take the same by directly, please share the code sample for taking the same.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework does not have a built-in 'GetXml' function. You can however reach the same through serialization with the `DataContractSerializer` . Something like this ('MyEntity'is your entity class):

```
     using ( FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite( "Data.xml" ) ) 
      {
          XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter( fs, Encoding.UTF8 );
          DataContractSerializer srlz = new DataContractSerializer( typeof( MyEntity) );
          srlz.Serialize( writer, recipe );
          writer.Close();
      }
```

There are some caveats though, see [this article](http://www.riggshill.com/home/taxonomy/term/37) for more info.